# How to remove a list item from fzf?

Tags: shell, fzf

I have the following script that pipes `git stash list` through `fzf`:

```
  git stash list\
    --color=always\
    --pretty=format:'%Cred%gd%Creset - %s%C(yellow)%d%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)' |\
  fzf\
    --ansi\
    --tiebreak=index\
    --header "<enter> view stash | <alt-enter> apply stash | <alt-d> drop stash | <ctrl-p> toggle preview window | <esc> quit"\
    --preview "echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | head -1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'git show --color=always %' | diff-so-fancy"\
    --preview-window "hidden"\
    --bind "ctrl-p:toggle-preview"\
    --bind "alt-d:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash drop %')+abort"\
    --bind "alt-enter:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash apply %')+abort"\
    --bind "enter:execute: (grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash show -p --color=always %' | diff-so-fancy | less -R) << 'FZF-EOF'
  {} FZF-EOF"
```

---

What I would like to do is hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and pass the selected line item to `git stash drop` AND to also remove this item from the list.

I was only able to achieve part of this with the following binding:

`--bind "alt-d:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash drop %')+abort"\`

While this does pass the item to `git stash drop` it also aborts (i.e. closes) the list.

How can I remove the item from the list after it is passed to `git stash drop` so that it no longer appears in the list, but that the list stays open?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`reload()` action](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/fzf/fzf.1.en.html#RELOAD_INPUT) to refresh the input list after your execution has finished:

```bash
--bind "alt-d:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash drop %')+reload(git stash list)
```

This does not include your initial arguments to `git stash list`, though. In order to preserve those without typing the same command twice, set and use the [`FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/fzf/fzf.1.en.html#FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND) variable instead of piping the command to `fzf`:

```bash
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="
    git stash list
    --color=always
    --pretty=format:'%Cred%gd%Creset - %s%C(yellow)%d%Creset %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)'"
fzf\
    --ansi\
    --tiebreak=index\
    --header "<enter> view stash | <alt-enter> apply stash | <alt-d> drop stash | <ctrl-p> toggle preview window | <esc> quit"\
    --preview "echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | head -1 | xargs -I % sh -c 'git show --color=always %' | diff-so-fancy"\
    --preview-window "hidden"\
    --bind "ctrl-p:toggle-preview"\
    --bind "alt-d:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash drop %')+reload($FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND)"\
    --bind "alt-enter:execute(echo {} | grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash apply %')+abort"\
    --bind "enter:execute: (grep -o 'stash@{[0-9]}' | xargs -I % sh -c 'git stash show -p --color=always %' | diff-so-fancy | less -R) << 'FZF-EOF'
{} FZF-EOF"
```

Comment: FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND does not contain fzf invocation. So if I do `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="seq 5"` and then run fzf, if you have it right, I'd expect to see 5 lines. But I'm not. So I guess there is something not right (missing fzf invocation). Am I right?

Comment: @MartinMucha Thanks for your comment. There was indeed something missing, but it wasn't the `fzf` command but the `git stash list` within `FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`. Furthermore, the variable needs to be exported in order to be available in the fzf binding. I updated my answer accordingly.